# Is it possible to type a React function component with TypeScript without using arrow functions?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Currently I have this React component typed as such:

```
import React, { FunctionComponent } from "react";

const HelloWorld : FunctionComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      Hello
    </div>
  );
}

export default HelloWorld;
```

I would not like to use arrow functions and write my component like so:

```
import React, { FunctionComponent } from "react";

function HelloWorld() {
  return (
    <div>
      Hello
    </div>
  );
}

export default HelloWorld;
```

Is it possible to type normal functions as `FunctionComponent`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `FunctionComponent` type basically boils down to a function that receives props and returns a `ReactElement`:

`(props: PropsWithChildren<P>, context?: any): ReactElement | null;`

So one option would be to type your non-arrow function accordingly:

```
function HelloWorld(): ReactElement {
  return (
    <div>
      Hello
    </div>
  );
}
```

The other option (which integrates better with the rest of the TS React ecosystem) is to store your function in a named variable:

```
interface SomeProps {
  someValue: number
}

const HelloWorld: FunctionComponent<SomeProps> = function HelloWorld({ someValue }) {
  return <div>Hi {someValue}</div>
}
```

Overall though I would recommend that you just use arrow functions as they offer benefits especially when it comes to JS scopes and the `this` reference.

Comment: Is it possible to add the props interface in the first example? And why the latter integrates better with the ecosystem?

Comment: That's what I meant by integrates better, you'll be able to properly leverage types and intellisense for your component props and state. I'm not aware of a way to make that work with the first example so in reality it has limited use cases. Why is it that you're trying to avoid using arrow functions?